# Deployment to Server fails with local Administrator

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

When trying deploy my Release to a Server using a local Admin Account at the Server i get the Message:

```
7-05-09T08:12:50.6866361Z 2017/05/09 10:12:50 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Getting File System Type of Destination \\server\C$\temp\

2017-05-09T08:12:50.6866361Z Access is denied.
```

during the robocopy to the remote server.

When trying to use my domain Account (also Administrator) it works without any problems.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the UNC path `\\server\C$\temp\` could be achieved by the local account you used as build service account.

I suggest that you use domain user to access the domain resources. Or you could share that folder `\\server\C$\temp\` to Everyone and give the Read and Write permission.

If you insist to use a local account, as a [workaround](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e50abc9a-2141-42ba-a6ee-b228a01acfe8/how-to-grant-network-access-to-local-user?forum=winservergen):

> local accounts on each member server where the shared folders are
>   stored will have to be created to directly map to the same
>   username/password combinations the users are using on each local
>   machine. For example, on client 1, local user named A, password xxxx,
>   on the server which stores the shares, you need to create a local user
>   named A with the same password xxxx.